# DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in JS and update only one page tag

Tags: jquery

I wrote a code that works perfectly but I would like to improve it because I fear it is not compatible with all OS.

Does the JS or JQUERY exist a command similar to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR as in PHP?

Is there a cleaner way to update only one page tag? I can not update the whole page otherwise my script in Ajax gives me other problems.

```
var a = location.href;
var b = a.substr(a.lastIndexOf("/")+1).split(/[?#]/)[0];
var num = Math.round(10*Math.random());
$(".contenitore_generale").load(b + "?ID="+num+" .contenitore_generale>*","");
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but I can tell you that the OS is not relevant to JS. Your question may be clearer if you give us details about what this code is doing and what you want to improve about it.

Comment: With the first 2 lines of code I want to get the name of the page I'm working on. The script works but not on all operating systems because it is not said that inside location.href there are always and only "/".

With the last line of code I update .contenitore_generale without reloading the whole page. The script works but I would like to know if there is a more robust and modern method to do the same thing. What I write is a big forcing.

Comment: Why this doesn't work?
$(".contenitore_generale").load("tag_content.php");

Comment: There are literally thousands of reasons that might not work. If you're struggling with it I'd suggest checking the console for an error after making the request, then starting a new question including that error and all relevant code.